# Trying to use touch id

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use touch id from a sample on one of xarmians blogs but it is given me an error. I do not no if its cause using the simulators registered test touch passed. But it is failing and another probelm i have is i am using story boards so my question is how do i push the view controller that is succsess and find out why touch id is faling.

```
partial void touchId(UIButton sender)
    {

        //Lets double check the device supports Touch ID
        if (context.CanEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, out error))
        {
            var replyHandler = new LAContextReplyHandler((success, error) =>
                {
                    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            if (success)
                            {
                                var newVC = new UIViewController();


                        PresentViewController(newVC, true, null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var alert = new UIAlertView("OOPS!", "Something went wrong.", null, "Oops", null);
                                alert.Show();
                            }
                        });
                });
            context.EvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, "Logging in with Touch ID", replyHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            var alert = new UIAlertView("Error", "TouchID not available", null, "BOOO!", null);
            alert.Show();
        }
    }
```

It is getting to this line of the application

```
var alert = new UIAlertView("OOPS!", "Something went wrong.", null, "Oops", null);
```

Comment: Why don't you log the value of `error`; that will give a clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: @Paulw11 THERE is no error as explained it just pops a blank view

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stuck i had to do the following.

```
var homeScreen = (UIViewController)Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("welcome");
        PresentViewController(homeScreen, true, () => { });
```

While making sure that the story board id  of the view controller i wanted to show was set to welcome